# Limit days selection to non past current month only in Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using [bootstrap-datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) and I need to configure it to allow only selection from current day to end day in the current month, I don't want to allow users to navigate trough months, is that possible? How? I read the docs but doesn't find any really helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You can use the **`startDate`** and **`endDate`** options of bootstrap datepicker.

2) Set today's date in startDate

```
var today = new Date();
```

3) To get last date of the month use this approach

```
var lastDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 0);
```

Finally

```
var today = new Date(); //Get today's date
var lastDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 0);  //To get the last date of today's month
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    startDate: today,
    endDate: lastDate
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/GX82L/)